# How to return an array from a list [Java]

Tags: java, arrays, list

Here is how my code is set up:

```
public String[] function(List<String[]> playerList){
i = 5
return playerList[i];
```

When I try to run this code, I get the error:

```
Array type expected; found: 'java.util.List<java.lang.String[]>'
```

I know I'm screwing something up by mixing my arrays and lists, what would be the right way of fixing this code, assuming I can't change my list input to an array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You access an element at an index in a `List` with a call to [`List.get(int index)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-) (not `[]`, that is accessing an element *in* an array). Like,

```
return playerList.get(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

not like c++, which can do operator overloading.

in java, `playerList` is a list, you cannot apply "[]" to it, but the list's element/item is an `Array` type (String[]). so, you should use `list.get()` and with it's element, you could use `[]` operator:  `(playerList.get(i))[0]`

Answer (score 0):

`playerList` is List type, for accessing element in the List you must call get function.
for example >> `playerList.get(0)` , then you will get element's value in index-0. In this case, you will return String of Array. And if you want accessing that Array element, you can use `playerList.get(0)[i]`

Answer (score 0):

So, you were trying to get an array of strings however, there could be two (2) things you wanted to take a look. First, you might want to specify `playerList` as an `ArrayList<String>` and then(second), you are trying to return `playerList[i]` as string and not as an array of string as specified `String[]`.

```
public String[] function(List<String[]> playerList){
  i = 5
  return playerList[i];
```

You might want to try this instead?

```
return playerList.toArray(new String[playerList.size()]);
```